# How to join two selects with no matching fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, pentaho, pdi

I need to create a DIM_TEAMS with these two selects. The first from NBA teams and the second from WNBA teams.

```
SELECT
E.pk_estado_eeuu, D.pk_division, LEAGUE, CODE, 
EQUIPO, CIUDAD, PABELLON, FUNDADO, PATROCINIO,
T.CONFERENCIA
FROM
STG_NBA_TEAMS T
INNER JOIN STG_TEAM_CODES TC ON(T.EQUIPO = TC.TEAM)
INNER JOIN DIM_Estados_EEUU E ON (T.ESTADO = E.codigo)
INNER JOIN DIM_Divisiones D ON(D.division = T.DIVISION)
```

[image: NBA select output]

```
SELECT
e.pk_estado_eeuu,LEAGUE,CODE, EQUIPO,
CIUDAD, WT.CONFERENCIA
FROM
STG_WNBA_TEAMS WT
INNER JOIN STG_TEAM_CODES TC ON(WT.EQUIPO = TC.TEAM)
INNER JOIN DIM_Estados_EEUU E ON (WT.ESTADO = E.nombre)
```

[image: WNBA select output]

This should be my expected output

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Do you want `UNION ALL`?

Comment: A JOIN is used to include columns of two tables. You need a UNION or UNION ALL to include rows of two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [union operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).  You'll need to `SELECT NULL` where you don't have a field from one to the other:

```
SELECT
    E.pk_estado_eeuu, 
    D.pk_division, 
    LEAGUE, 
    CODE, 
    EQUIPO, 
    CIUDAD, 
    PABELLON, 
    FUNDADO, 
    PATROCINIO,
    T.CONFERENCIA
FROM
STG_NBA_TEAMS T
INNER JOIN STG_TEAM_CODES TC ON(T.EQUIPO = TC.TEAM)
INNER JOIN DIM_Estados_EEUU E ON (T.ESTADO = E.codigo)
INNER JOIN DIM_Divisiones D ON(D.division = T.DIVISION)
UNION
SELECT
    e.pk_estado_eeuu,
    NULL AS pk_division,
    LEAGUE,
    CODE, 
    EQUIPO,
    CIUDAD, 
    NULL AS PABELLON, 
    NULL AS FUNDADO, 
    NULL AS PATROCINIO,
    WT.CONFERENCIA
FROM
STG_WNBA_TEAMS WT
INNER JOIN STG_TEAM_CODES TC ON(WT.EQUIPO = TC.TEAM)
INNER JOIN DIM_Estados_EEUU E ON (WT.ESTADO = E.nombre)
```

Comment: You could probably optimize the query by doing `UNION ALL` on NBA and WNBA teams, and then join the team code and state tables just once (instead of one per subquery here).

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using Pentaho Data Integration tool using sorted merge step which is available under joins category from design section.

[image]

[image]